# Can't figure out this incrementing and decrementing problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a python exercise where I have to reduce a circle from 50px to 10px. When 10px has been reached the circle has to be expanded back to 50px. I am stuck right now as I am able to reduce the circle from 50px to 10px but when I try to expand it back to 50px, it gets stuck on 10-11px.

Here is the code:

```
import simplegui

WIDTH = 100
HEIGHT = 100
RADIUS = 50
color = 'Green'
iterations = 0

def draw_handler(canvas):
    global iterations, RADIUS, size_reach
    iterations += 1
    canvas.draw_circle((100, 100), RADIUS, 1, color, color)
    if(iterations%6==0):
        if(RADIUS!=10):
            RADIUS-=1
            print("1st: " + str(RADIUS))
        elif(RADIUS == 10):
            if(RADIUS!=50):
                RADIUS+=1
                print("2nd: " + str(RADIUS))

frame = simplegui.create_frame('Testing', WIDTH*2, HEIGHT*2)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.start()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must keep state variable that indicate your current direction.

```
color = 'Green'
WIDTH = 100
HEIGHT = 100
MIN_RADIUS = 10
MAX_RADIUS = 50

iterations = 0
direction = -1
radius = 50


def draw_handler(canvas):
    global iterations, radius, direction
    iterations += 1
    canvas.draw_circle((WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2), radius, 1, color, color)
    radius = radius + direction
    if direction < 0 and radius <= MIN_RADIUS:
        print(f'iterations={iterations}, radius={radius}')
        direction = 1
    if direction > 0 and radius >= MAX_RADIUS:
        print(f'iterations={iterations}, radius={radius}')
        direction = 0  # done
```